# symfony form 'this value should not be blank' error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have an entity and a form and I want to remove the password field.

```
#[ORM\Column(
        type: 'string',
        name: 'password',
        length: 20,
        nullable: false
    )]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(
        max: 20
        nullable: true
    )]
    private string $password
```

I changed it to one below and also generated and run the migration.

```
 #[Gedmo\Versioned]
    #[ORM\Column(
        type: 'string',
        name: 'password',
        length: 20,
        nullable: true
    )]
    private string $password;
```

removed it from form builder as well as twig view but I am getting **'this value should not be blank error'** when submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

If it's nullable then you should try this

```
private ?string $password;
```

Comment: has nothing todo with the constraints.

Comment: it only happens on production environment.any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use validation groups, so you can exclude the password field.

you can even include the password field all the time - but dont validate it at `NotBlank`.
In your controller you test if empty  and only if not hash the new password.

for example:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): FormBuilderInterface
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, ['label' => 'Name', 'required' => false])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['label' => 'Email'])
            ->add(
                'plainPassword',
                RepeatedType::class,
                [
                    'type' => PasswordType::class,
                    'label' => 'Password',
                    'invalid_message' => 'user.password.mustmatch',
                    'first_options' => ['label' => 'Password'],
                    'second_options' => ['label' => 'Password repeat'],
                ]
            )
            ->add('role', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Role',
                'placeholder' => 'generic.select',
                'choices' => UserRoleInterface::FORM_USER_ROLES_ADMIN,
                // 'attr' => ['class' => 'select2'],
            ])

        ;

        return $builder;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => User::class,
                'validation_groups' => function (Form $userType) {
                    $user = $userType->getData();
                    if (null === $user->getId()) {
                        return ['Default', 'Create'];
                    }

                    return ['Default'];
                },
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

See the validation group - if we dont have an ID then we are in "create" mode and the password field is mandatory. if there is an ID we are in edit mode - and password has not to be set again.

And as example the user entity:

```
#[UniqueEntity('email', groups: ['create'])]
class User implements UserInterface, UserEmailInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface, UserRoleInterface, UserPasswordResetInterface
{
    protected ?string $id = null;

    #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['create', 'update-password'])]
    #[Assert\Length(min: 8, groups: ['create', 'update-password'])]
    protected ?string $plainPassword = null;

    #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['create', 'update-password', 'Default'])]
    #[Assert\Email(groups: ['create', 'update-password', 'Default'])]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 200, groups: ['create', 'update-password', 'Default'])]
    protected ?string $email = null;

    protected ?string $password = null;
    protected array $roles = [];
    protected ?string $role = null;
    [...] 
}
```

The relevant controller part:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if (null !== $user->getPlainPassword()) {
        $passwordHelper->updateUserPassword($user);
    }
    $manager->flush();
}
```

Comment: the thing is it only happens on the production environment .any ideas?